# Upload only unique values to Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load a CSV file to the Big Query. My CSV file could contain duplicate rows. I am seeking help to know if there is a way, I could upload only the unique values from the CSV file using bq load command from CLI.

For example, if my CSV file contain below values:

```
emp_id, emp_name
1,a
2,b
3,c
1,a
4,d
5,e
3,c
```

I want only the unique values to be uploaded to the Big Query Table:

```
emp_id, emp_name
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e
```

Currently I am removing the duplicate values manually before uploading to the Big Query Table.
I am expecting to know if there is a switch/parameter, I could use to upload only unique values using "bq load" command from cloud shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bq load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load) is not capable of applying any transform to your data. What you can do is pre process your file prior to loading it via `bq load`. You can use the command below in cloud shell to remove duplicates:

```
head -1 test.csv > temp && sort -u test.csv | head -n -1 > temp_2 && cat temp temp_2 > new_test.csv && rm temp*
```

Assuming `test.csv` contains your data, the command above gets the header saving it to `temp`. Then separately it gets the unique values and saves it to `temp_2`. Build the clean file by concatenating `temp` and `temp_2` and naming the file as `new_test.csv`.

You can now use `new_test.csv` as input in `bq load`. See test below:

[image]

But if you have bigger data than this, I recommend using a programming language to create a logic to clean your data.